# DataTemplate doesn't properly bind the properties as specified

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have the following **DataTemplate** in **DataTemplates.xaml**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ExcelReportVM}">
    <local:ExcelReport DoubleClickHandler="{Binding}">
        <local:ExcelReport.RowColorConverter>
            <local:ReportRowColorConverter/>
        </local:ExcelReport.RowColorConverter>
    </local:ExcelReport>
</DataTemplate>
```

I make sure that this DataTemplate is usable within the application scope via the following **App.xaml** definition:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplates.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And this is my control **ExcelReport.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ExcelReport"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              ....
             xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding .}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ExcelReportVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" x:Name="grid" Background="White"
                           HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"

                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

My code behind: **ExcelReport.xaml.cs**

```
   public partial class ExcelReport : UserControl
    {


  public static readonly DependencyProperty RowColorConverterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
              "RowColorConverter",
              typeof(IValueConverter),
              typeof(ExcelReport),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRowColorConverterChanged))
            );

    public IValueConverter RowColorConverter
        {
            get { return (IValueConverter)GetValue(RowColorConverterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RowColorConverterProperty, value); }
        }

   public ExcelReport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

 private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    Debug.Assert(DataContext.GetType()==typeof(ExcelReportVM)); //DataContext is correct
    Debug.Assert(RowColorConverter!=null); //but this is null
  }
}
```

I've no idea why I can successfully bind the DataContext, but the `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ExcelReportVM}">` that I define is not used, I thought everything inside the `DataTemplates.xaml` is accessible to ExcelReport.xaml?

Note: There is no error in the output window, and there is no exception been thrown anywhere in the code.

Comment: Does your output window have any errors in it when you run this?

Comment: @JBrooks, no, no error at all.

Comment: Where you are using this `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ExcelReportVM}">` ? I can't see that in your present code.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, it's inside the `DataTemplates.xaml`, the first of the code block

Comment: @Graviton I am saying where u r using it ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, maybe there is a confusion here, I thought that by specifying `<UserControl.DataContext><local:ExcelReportVM/> </UserControl.DataContext>` I am already using it. Let me know if this is not the case, and show me how to properly use the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: If it is a `ContentControl`, then you have to set its `Content` as `<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>` , then based on `DataType` of `SomeProperty` correct `DataTemplate` is picked up.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, would you like to expand this into an answer?

Comment: To what control are you expecting your DataTemplate to be applied?

Comment: @mm8 , to any control that has 'ExcelReportVM' as datacontext, isn't it?

Comment: No, definitely not. There is no DataTemplate being automatically applied to a UserControl that has a DataContext of a specific type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fix the problem, I don't set the `UserControl.DataContext` to `ExcelReportVM` at `ExcelReport.xaml`; instead, I set the `ContentControl.Content` to `ExcelReportVM` at `MainWindow.xaml`.

Updated code at **ExcelReport.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ExcelReport"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              ....
             xmlns:syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding .}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
  <!--  <UserControl.DataContext>   this is not longer needed
        <local:ExcelReportVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext> -->
    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}" x:Name="grid" Background="White"
                           HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"

                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Code at **MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Syncfusion:RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized"
        Syncfusion:SkinStorage.VisualStyle="Office2013"
        xmlns:Syncfusion="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf">

    <Grid x:Name="ExcelReport22">
        <ContentControl>   <!-- this is where the ExcelReportVM is binded to -->
            <local:ExcelReportVM/>
        </ContentControl>

    </Grid>
</Syncfusion:RibbonWindow>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `ContentControl`, then you have to set its `Content` as `<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>` , then based on `DataType` of `SomeProperty` correct `DataTemplate` is picked up.

Comment: `"{Binding SomeProperty`-- what properly? Can you be more explicit in your code?

Comment: @Graviton `SomeProperty` is normally `ViewModel` and its type should match `local:ExcelReportVM`.